# sounds of polygonal ring chimes of metal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, vibrations, harmonics

Suppose we have a number of rings, each of them is constructed from some mass of wrought iron or steel: each ring is a polygon, which I would like to suppose is constructed without welding (so they are cast and then machined to tolerances). The side length is $a$ and the radius of each side (assume they are locally cylindrical away from the joins) is $r$. 
They are suspended at a point (like the musical instrument, the triangle)

- If the rings are of constant internal area, what frequency sound do they make when struck?
- If the rings are of constant side length, what frequency sound do they make when struck

Comment: What have you done so far in looking at this? Also, the sounds you hear when playing the triangle instrument greatly depends on how and where you strike it. I don't think a general "strike" is enough to specify a solution

Comment: I do not know where to look: this is not a homework problem, it's something that's been nagging at me for years.

Comment: I think that there's a symmetry argument which reduces the number of strike-places one needs to think about. A strike is likely /impact of some force of $n$ Newtons at a point on the surface at some angle. But I don't know where to go next. The Laplacian I can probably do numerically, but I'm unsure about where to go analytically here.

Comment: The homework-and-exercises tag isn't just for assigned homework problems

Comment: This is tricky! I assume your chimes are solid, not hollow, and they don't have a gap (like an orchestral triangle has), so they should be fairly tonal (whereas a triangle is fairly atonal, due to the gap). I can't find much relevant info, but some info relating to bells & chimes ought to apply to your polygons, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_tone I assume the polygonal geometry could have *some* influence on the partial tones ("harmonics") of these instruments, compared to a straight chime bar, but I have no idea how much.

Comment: @PM2Ring I had been under the impression that the obstruction to /oh you have some mass of metal, here's the tone it should make/, is that resonant modes involve standing waves in both direction, and I don't have an immediate way of modelling those. I may end up buliding/constructing this.